# JWT validation in class based view django

Tags: python, django, graphql, jwt, django-graphql-jwt

I've implemented jwt authentication in django using Django-graphql-jwt library, now I want to allow get/post on my endpoint (/graphql) only for requests with JWT token. There are examples in django-graphql-jwt documentation like @login_required, but I don't want to put a decorator above every query and mutation. So, I've decided to restrict an access to a view. I added path('graphql/', PrivateGraphQLView.as_view()) in url.py but how can I implement request checking for a valid token in the header?

```
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView


class PrivateGraphQLView(GraphQLView):
    pass
```

Comment: https://github.com/graphql-python/flask-graphql/issues/53

Answer (score 0):

Find my answer here [JWT Authentication: Use UI token to authenticate Graphene/Django (GraphQL) queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884611/jwt-authentication-use-ui-token-to-authenticate-graphene-django-graphql-queri)
But actually I've decided not to go deep down as it's just a simple app, and I need at least one mutation (get a token) open, so decorators from django-graphql-jwt should be enough